# AutocompleteTextView not showing up in android

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

Am trying to populate list of items when user enters at least one character in autocompletetextview. GetView and get count methods in my custom adapter is getting called, but not populating out the auto completion list. Any help much appreciated. I have seen so many questions like this in SO and none helped.

```
specialityEditAutoCompleteTextView = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.specialityEditAutoCompleteText);
        specialityEditAutoCompleteTextView.setThreshold(1);
    specialityEditAutoCompleteTextView.setAdapter(new MyAutocompleteTextViewAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,android.R.id.text1,Cache.getCache().specialities));
            specialityEditAutoCompleteTextView.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                specialityEditAutoCompleteTextView.showDropDown();
                ((ArrayAdapter)specialityEditAutoCompleteTextView.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

            }
        });
```

Below is my Custom Adapter class

```
    public MyAutocompleteTextViewAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, List<ItemPicker> objects) {
    super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, objects);
    this.context = context;
    this.loId = resource;
    this.textViewId = textViewResourceId;
    items = objects;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;

    if (v == null) {
        v = ((LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(loId, null);
    }
    ((TextView) v.findViewById(android.R.id.text1)).setText(items.get(position).displayableTitle());
    return v;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return this.items.size();
}
```

Below is the layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="i_hash_in.dsp.com.myschool.NewTeacherProfileActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:fitsSystemWindows="true" >
        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="240dp"  app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlwaysCollapsed|enterAlways|exitUntilCollapsed">
        <ImageView android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" android:background="@mipmap/fourcolor" android:scaleType="fitCenter"/>


            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_width="200dp" android:background="@drawable/ic_local_see_black_48dp"
                android:layout_height="200dp" android:id="@+id/takePhotoButton"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
 <AutoCompleteTextView android:hint="Speciality" android:completionThreshold="2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:id="@+id/specialityEditAutoCompleteText"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

 </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```